# Getting 404 page not found error while checking from postman

Tags: go, routes, google-cloud-platform

I'm running the below code using `goapp serve`. Somehow getting `404 page not found` error while checking from postman. Could you please help me to fix this

```
    package hello

        import (
        "fmt"
        "net/http"

        "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
    )

    func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
        fmt.Fprint(w, "Welcome!\n")
    }

    func Hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, ps httprouter.Params) {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "hello, %s!\n", ps.ByName("name"))
    }

    func init() {
        router := httprouter.New()
        router.GET("/", Index)
        router.GET("/hello/:name", Hello)
//log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))

    }
```

In postman passing endpoint 
`http://localhost:8080/hello/hyderabad`

Comment: Why is `http.ListenAndServe` commented out? You're not actually starting an http server. Are you expecting something else to do it for you? If so, how is it aware of your router?

Comment: if I run the code using goapp serve command it's automatically hosts at 8080, When used `http.HandleFunc("/register", RegisterHandler)` i have not mentioned the `http.ListenAndServe`

Comment: Ok, but you're not showing where you register your router. If your code is at shown, the http server does not know about your router.

Comment: How it works when I moved to GCP with out mention `http.ListenAndServe`

Comment: have you tried `http.Handle("/", router)` as the last line of your `init()` function?

Comment: Thanks @Marc I have added `http.Handle("/", router)` and now it is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on my comment above:
A handler function (or the router from `julienschmidt/httprouter`) does not register itself. Instead, it needs to be registered with the http server.

The simplest way to do that is usually do register with the default ServeMux using: `http.Handle("/", router)`

Thus, changing the init function to the following will work:

```
   func init() {
        router := httprouter.New()
        router.GET("/", Index)
        router.GET("/hello/:name", Hello)
        http.Handle("/", router)
    }
```